# context.getImageData() on localhost?

Tags: html, canvas

I have the following snippet of code and I'm trying to run it from localhost (OSX, running XAMPP):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var cx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var myImg = new Image();
    myImg.src = 'images/lion.jpg';

    $(myImg).load(function() {
        cx.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
        var imgData = cx.getImageData(0,0,150,150);
    });
```

But when I run it I get this error from the console:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
site.js:11Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

I found some similar questions here and I know that this has something to do with the fact that I'm working locally and this wouldn't happen if I was trying to access the image from the same domain. I don't know if this makes sense, but it's what I understood.

My question is, how can I make this work in a local dev environment?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Serve your html with an HTTP server, for example, Apache or Nginx.

Mac OSX comes with Python installed, so you can simply start an HTTP server by opening a terminal, then input:

```
cd /path/to/my/work/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then open `http://localhost:8000/` in your browser. This should work.

Comment: Not always possible. How can this be worked around in the situations we are in where we're putting a site on a CD to be run locally on a target machine via Autorun.inf and therefore cannot set up a server or rely on one (or any network access) being available?

Works a charm in all other browsers but in Chrome console says:

"Kinetic warning: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. "

Sad times

Answer (score 1):

Trying a different browser might help. This happened to me on Chromium and just by switching to Firefox I was able to continue debugging locally.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combo of solutions (see [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript))

Steps:

1. Transform the image to base64 string.
2. Assign that as the src of the Image js object.
3. Draw on canvas

Code:

```
// helper to transform to base64
// see other question for more help
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

var canvas        = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx           = canvas.getContext("2d");
var png           = new Image();
var backgroundSrc = ".....";

png.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(png, 0, 0);
};

toDataUrl(backgroundSrc, function(base64Img) {
  png.src = base64Img;
});
```

I know this solution is NOT optimal, but it worked for me AND **it helps when the image does not come from the same origin**.

I'm posting this for anyone that encounters the same problem.