# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am getting this error in Chrome and Opera Browsers:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

The code is working fine in Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, and Safari. But I need to fix it in Chrome and Opera. Please help me to find a solution to fix this problem?

I am getting this error at this line

```
imgData = ctx.getImageData(x1,y1,w,h);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Answer (score 15):

May be this will help, as you have mentioned cross origin so try this,

```
 var UimageObj = new Image();
```

crossOrigin has to be set to enable the canvas data to be saved.The source image should have `access-control-allow-origin` set to `*` or a chosen domain

```
UimageObj.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';   // crossOrigin attribute has to be set before setting src.If reversed, it wont work.  
UimageObj.src = obj_data.srcUser;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "crossOrigin attribute has to be set before setting src.If reversed, it wont work." This is important, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you load your html file from disk using: `file://path/to/your/file.html`, then Google Chrome and Opera will raise error at line including: `imgData = ctx.getImageData(x1,y1,w,h);`

Solution is simple: start web server (apache, nginx) put your html file somewhere at web server and load your html file from: `http://localhost/somewhere/file.html`