# Console Log: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, console

Hey I'm trying to implement a jquery plug in called [backgroundcheck](https://github.com/kennethcachia/background-check) and it gives me the console log error of: 
"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." I have done everything he says to do in the instructions but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

These are the three errors under the main error in the drop down menu.

```
calculatePixelBrightness VM682 background-check.min.js:571
processTargets VM682 background-check.min.js:631
check VM682 background-check.min.js:766
```

Here's a [screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/t4y8eq.jpg) of it as well.

Comment: Why is your link to `foo.com`?

Comment: oops, sorry, fixed it

Comment: Can you include some of the code you were using to get the error? It is not obvious when looking at the github readme where it would be caused.

Comment: Thats the thing, I literally copied verbatim what he did so I'm really just looking for information about this error log, it seems really rare and there arent many pages about it.

Answer (score 5):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pd57edsd/)***

The error is a result of the image being located at a different domain. There is a surprisingly simple remedy to this though, which is to add the attribute `crossDomain = "anonymous"` to the image element itself.

For example,

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UnnoYbv.jpg" crossOrigin="anonymous" draggable="false" />
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm using only local images! That's the weird thing. Please look at the update. Thanks SO much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

This question seems as duplication of:

[Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688168/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-getimagedata-on-canvasrenderingcont)

The solution is probably the same. When you load your html file from disk using: `file://path/to/your/file.html`, then Google Chrome and Opera will raise error at line including: `imgData = ctx.getImageData(x1,y1,w,h);`

Solution is simple: start web server (apache, nginx) put your html file somewhere at web server and load your html file from: `http://localhost/somewhere/file.html`