# Changing the header background color from images of the bootstrap carousel using color-thief

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have used the `bootstrap carousal` and  able to change the color of `header background` using `color thief` of one image only.

**But in carousal there are multiple image changing with time.I am not able to get the image id from carousel for each image and set  the color of header with changing of  image using color thief .**

This is the code I have tried,  please tell me how to change the header background color according to change of carousal image. Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<section class="block">
    <div style="padding:42px">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:15px solid rgb(250, 250, 250);padding: 0px;">
            <div id="myDiv">

                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides (228, 226, 224) -->

                    <div class="carousel-inner reduce-height" role="listbox">

                        <div class="item active">
                            <img id="myimg" src="images/titanic.jpg" alt="Chania">

                            <div class="absolute-div">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Unforgettable Moments</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img id="myimg2" src="images/beautiful-couple-widescreen.jpg" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="absolute-div">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Cherishable Memories</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my code for color thief and carousal

```
<script>
    $(window).ready(function() {

        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
        });


        var sourceImage = document.getElementById("myimg");
        var colorThief = new ColorThief();
        var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
        document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color + ")";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify which `img` is `active` currently using below event of bootstrap carousel

```
$('#yourcarouselid').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
      $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
           var sourceImage=$(e.relatedTarget).find('img'); //get the active sliding image
           var colorThief=new ColorThief();
           var color = colorThief.getColor(sourceImage);
           document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + color+")";
      }); 
});
```

---

**Update**

Just change one line above:

```
var sourceImage=$(e.relatedTarget).find('img')[0]
```

Comment: I have tried your method but its throwing this error   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
2color-thief.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

Comment: @henrycharles updated answer.,.. check and let me knw!!

Comment: thanks for helping yes its working but its working for mozilla firefox only its not working in google chrome why is that so ?

Comment: This is the error coming in google chrome--->Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.                                                      And also after sometime in mozilla firefox unresponsive script is popping up ..please help me to clarify the concepts why this is happening thanks in advance

Comment: @henrycharles.. After I googled the exception you are getting I got **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)** and **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688168/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-getimagedata-on-canvasrenderingcont)** link which might be helpful to you to understand. Its not problem with the code I gave. Its now something to do with your internal coding.

Comment: thanks for supporting its now working after deploying in the server

Comment: Cool.. Happy coding.. :)