# How to create thumbnail for uploaded images on DropZone.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dropzone.js

With below code i got all uploaded images with `DropZone`,but i now i have a simple problem, it already showing Original images as thumbnail but i need to show thumbnail with `base64` same as `dropzone` made when want to upload new image.

**dropzone.js**

```
 init: function() {
         var thisDropzone = this;
        var pageid = $("#pageid").val();
        $.getJSON('plugin/dropzone/get_item_images.php?id='+pageid, function(data) { 

            $.each(data, function(key,value){ 

                var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size }; 

                thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
                thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "/admin/uploads/"+value.name);
                thisDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);

            });
        });

      },
```

So the problem is with this code i able to show uploaded images with `dropzone` but it show thumbnail with original images not real thumbnail that created with `base64`. `dropzone` made thumbnail with `base64` when you want to upload new image, i want to show thumbnail like this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use createThumbnailFromUrl , orginally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412921/3150751)

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
myDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, '/your-image.jpg');
```

Comment: In case if the function is not defined, update your dropzone library.

Comment: You sir, save my day. In the Dropzone FAQ don't say that it need to be the mockFile and the whole url as second parameter. Thanks

Comment: How to specify the thumbnail style? I have created a B&W versions that I would like to show as thumbnails, how to do that?