# Dropzone createThumbnailFromUrl() issue

Tags: image, thumbnails, laravel-5.4, dropzone.js

I need to add pre-existing image files to dropzone by using **Laravel 5.4**. This is why I use `createThumbnailFromUrl()` function. But it does not generate images properly. Instead it shows them in blank way. I used that link ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gksmdrr/11/)) for that purpose. I googled a lot, tried several ways, but it did not help:

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='{{asset("js/dropzone/min/dropzone.min.js")}}'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  Dropzone.options.addImages = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  addRemoveLinks: true,
     // The setting up of the dropzone
     init:function() {

        // Add server images
        var myDropzone = this;
        var existingFiles = [
        { name: "Filename 1.pdf", size: 12345678,imageUrl:'http://img.tfd.com/wn/93/17E8B3-awful.png' },
        { name: "Filename 2.pdf", size: 12345678,imageUrl:'http://img.tfd.com/wn/93/17E8B3-awful.png' },
        { name: "Filename 3.pdf", size: 12345678,imageUrl:'http://img.tfd.com/wn/93/17E8B3-awful.png' },
        { name: "Filename 4.pdf", size: 12345678,imageUrl:'http://img.tfd.com/wn/93/17E8B3-awful.png' },
        { name: "Filename 5.pdf", size: 12345678,imageUrl:'http://img.tfd.com/wn/93/17E8B3-awful.png' }
        ];

        for (i = 0; i < existingFiles.length; i++) {

           // alert(existingFiles[i].imageUrl);

           myDropzone.emit("addedfile",existingFiles[i]);
           myDropzone.files.push(existingFiles[i]);
           myDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(existingFiles[i], existingFiles[i].imageUrl, function() {
            myDropzone.emit("complete", existingFiles[i]);
        }, "anonymous");

       }
   },
};
</script>
```

Here is the result :( :
[image]

P.S: Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm facing the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate thumbnails for images stored on the server using dropzone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412229/how-to-generate-thumbnails-for-images-stored-on-the-server-using-dropzone)

Answer (score 18):

had the same issue with dropzone 5.3

this fixed it for me

```
let mockFile = { name: "Loaded File", dataURL: relURL };
dropzoneInst.files.push(mockFile);
dropzoneInst.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
dropzoneInst.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile,
    dropzoneInst.options.thumbnailWidth, 
    dropzoneInst.options.thumbnailHeight,
    dropzoneInst.options.thumbnailMethod, true, function (thumbnail) 
        {
            dropzoneInst.emit('thumbnail', mockFile, thumbnail);
        });
dropzoneInst.emit('complete', mockFile);
```

Comment: This leads to CORS issues if your image is not in the same server as your website.

Answer (score 2):

I am attaching for reference my solution, based on many previous answers, but mostly on Raphael Eckmayer. This is how it is done to make it work well with **Django 3.0.5** and **dropzone.js 5.7.0**. Maybe it is not **the** best solution, but it works.

I am sending my current images from Django view using new template tag json_script that packs my list of files prepared in Django into JSON. Basically in my template I have this:

```
{{ images|json_script:"images" }}
```

Then I process this in my script. Here is entire script from my site, hope that will help someone.

**EDIT:**

I had an issue with this code that if I add new pictures to the dropzone together with the old one from database I got this form submitted twice. In first pass I get pictures from dropzone.js, but also all fields since I am copying them from the form. And then, on second pass, I am submitting form again but now without pictures. My view actually was handling this well and storing data, but when I started to write down how to handle removed pictures on form edit I had issue with this, so I decided to handle this differently. Please note that code is now changed and instead of submitting form twice I am sending entire form and pictures with dropzone, but after **successmultiple** I am just redirecting to other page. Everything is updated and stored then. So the change is in the successmultiple part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var first_time = true;
        var old_images = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('images').textContent)

        var myDropzoneX = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone", {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            url: "{% url 'site_report_edit' report_id=1 %}",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            thumbnailWidth: 400,
            thumbnailHeight: 400,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 12,

            init: function() {
                var myDropzone = this;
                var addButton = document.getElementById("submit-btn");

                if (old_images) {
                    console.log(old_images);

                    for (x in old_images) {
                        var mockFile = {
                            name: old_images[x].name,
                            size: old_images[x].size,
                            kind: 'image',
                            dataURL: old_images[x].urlich,
                            accepted: true
                        }
                        myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
                        myDropzone.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
                        createThumbnail(mockFile);

                        console.log(old_images[x].name, old_images[x].urlich);
                    }

                    function createThumbnail(temp) {
                        myDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(temp,
                            myDropzone.options.thumbnailWidth,
                            myDropzone.options.thumbnailHeight,
                            myDropzone.options.thumbnailMethod, true, function (thumbnail) {
                                myDropzone.emit('thumbnail', temp, thumbnail);
                                myDropzone.emit("complete", temp);
                            });
                    }
                    myDropzone._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();
                }

                addButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("dropzone-form").submit();
                    }
                });

                this.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
                    setTimeout(function (){
                        {#document.getElementById("dropzone-form").submit();#}
                        window.location.href = "/admin/report/{{ report_id }}";
                    }, 1000);
                });
            },

            sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                var formEl = document.getElementById("dropzone-form");

                if (first_time) {
                    for (var i=0; i<formEl.elements.length; i++){
                        formData.append(formEl.elements[i].name, formEl.elements[i].value)
                        first_time = false;
                    }
                }

                formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));
                formData.append("image", file.name);
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Please note that there are some comments and some writing to console.log, but you can obviously get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Use these files:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css

It worked for me.

Comment: please clarify your answer

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, however I was facing the same issue. The problem I was having was a race condition where only the last thumbnail was loaded and the others were stuck before completing, because i changed before createThumbnailFromUrl was getting it's data. Putting the call inside function did the trick for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var temp = { name: images[i], dataURL: images[i] };
    myDropzone.files.push(temp);
    myDropzone.emit("addedfile", temp);
    createThumbnail(temp);
 }

function createThumbnail(temp) {
    myDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(temp,
        myDropzone.options.thumbnailWidth,
        myDropzone.options.thumbnailHeight,
        myDropzone.options.thumbnailMethod, true, function (thumbnail) {
            myDropzone.emit('thumbnail', temp, thumbnail);
            myDropzone.emit("complete", temp);
        });
}
```

My answer is inspired by BLitande's, which helped me getting it to kind of work in the first place.