# Change the canvas fillstyle without overlapping with previous color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to change fillstyle on focus in and focus out event. When the event call multiple time it's overlapping. Here my code:

```
function FillColorToFields(id, isOnFocus) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var coordinates = $('#hidCoord_' + id).val().split(',');
    if (isOnFocus) {
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,0,0.1)";
        context.fillRect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
    } else {
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
        context.fillRect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify your problem in a clearer manner? And how about a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vm47p2sk/1/

Comment: In my case, I have to load an image to canvas and draw rectangle on it. Please check this
http://jsfiddle.net/vm47p2sk/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `context.clearRect(x, y, width, height)`. Its purpose is to erase any previously drawn content of the rectangle (check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)). See [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbf1fnbh/) for an example.

Comment: In my case, I have to load an image to canvas and draw rectangle on it. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/vm47p2sk/3

Comment: Oooh, much more fun! You would have to use `getImageData` and `putImageData` to restore the original state. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TadeasPetak/vm47p2sk/7/) for an example. You then run into an issue of a **tainted** canvas, solution to which is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data).

Answer (score 0):

I set the image as canvas background image instead of drawing it to canvas. It's working fine now.

http://jsfiddle.net/vm47p2sk/8/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<a id = "green" href="#">On focus</a>
<a id = "transparent" href="#">On focus out</a>



 $('#myCanvas').css("background-image", "url(https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png)");
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context  = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.strokeStyle = "#009900";
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeRect (5, 5, 100, 100);

$('#green').click(function (){
        context.clearRect (8, 8, 94, 94);  
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,0,0.1)";
        context.fillRect (8, 8, 94, 94);  
});

$('#transparent').click(function (){
        context.clearRect (8, 8, 94, 94); 
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)";
        context.fillRect (8, 8, 94, 94);  
});
```