# Modify pixels in remote image in plain html/js

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript, I would like to modify the brightness of any remote image given in an input form.
I have tried to use Canvas but I got this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data).
I want the following code to work directly via "file:///test.html". How can I simply achieve that ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function readImg() {
    img = new Image();
    url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    document.getElementById('showImg').innerHTML='<img src="'+ url +'" />';
    img.src = url;
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // not working !!
    brightness(imgData);

  }

    function brightness(imgData) {
      var dataimg = imgData.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataimg.size; i += 4 ) {
        dataimg[i] += 10;
        dataimg[i+1] += 10;
        dataimg[i+2] += 10;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="url" type="text" onChange="readImg()"></input>
<div id='showImg'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give Chrome explicit access to local files from local html files.
You have to run Chrome with **--allow-file-access-from-files** flag.

```
"C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

You can find more info about it here as it was already discussed: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18587027/4103991

@EDIT://
Execute commands related to img element inside img.onload event handler.
Your code should look somewhat like that:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function readImg() {
    img = new Image();
    url = document.getElementById('url').value;

    document.getElementById('showImg').innerHTML='<img src="'+ url +'" />';
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        brightness(imgData);
    }

    img.src = url;
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  }

    function brightness(imgData) {
      var dataimg = imgData.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataimg.size; i += 4 ) {
        dataimg[i] += 10;
        dataimg[i+1] += 10;
        dataimg[i+2] += 10;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="url" type="text" onChange="readImg()"></input>
<div id='showImg'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there no other way without changing flags ? :/

Comment: Unfortunately no, as it's for security reasons. 

If someone, for example, sent you an HTML file which would dig for your local files and send them to remote server, would you be happy that browser allowed for that to happen?

Comment: Thank you but I still get this error : `` Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.`

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your last comment.