# can't get pixel data from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixel

I am loading a black and white image from my computer on a web page and then drawing the image in a canvas. Then I want to retrieve the color of the first pixel. Here's the JavaScript function I am using:

```
function loadImage(){
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("first");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var z1=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data[0];
    document.getElementById("1").value=z1;
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Any ideas how I can achieve my requirement? This is part of a project I'm working on where I want to create a genetic algorithm that draws a given picture. An important part of this project is comparing the pixels from the initial image (loaded in a canvas) to a canvas populated by pseudo-random pixels. I then introduce small variance to the pixels to evolve it towards the initial image.

If I draw the canvas manually (using fillRect) I can retrieve the pixel data using 'getImageData'. However, when I draw the canvas using an image (drawImage), I get the above mentioned error.

Please help.

Edit: I've looked at: [How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

But this is not the case. I am loading the image from my own computer. I simply have the .html, .js and .png files in the same folder and run the .html file.

Comment: I was about to say the same.  The answer there explains the issue...I'm guessing you're loading your image from another url or source?

Comment: I am loading the image from my own computer, like this:
<img id="first" src="first.png" width="64" height="64" border="1px"">

I found that answer too, but I couldn't understand how to fix this.

Comment: From what I was able to understand, I need to set the "crossOrigin" attribute of the <img> to "Anonymous" and "set the following header on the server": Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*". I can't add that attribute to my <img> tag, because I get the following error: "Image from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.". And I don't know how to set the header on the server. The server is my own PC. I run a HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've installed WAMP, put everything in the "www" folder and ran it from there. Worked.

Comment: Since your question is a duplicate of previously asked questions, you might want to delete your answer and your question. ;-)