# Mapped color transformation on cors tainted image

Tags: javascript, canvas, cors, webgl, webgl2

I need to transform colors in an image obtained from an s3 server which disallows crossOrigin.

This is the functionality I need:

```
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const colors = [25,50,100,255];
  const data = imageData.data;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if(data[i] == 1){data[i] = colors[1]}
    if(data[i] == 2){data[i] = colors[2]}
    if(data[i] == 3){data[i] = colors[3]}
  }
```

but got tainted by crossOrigin error:

[image]

**I know I can not use `getImageData` in this case.** I don't want to read the image data.

But maybe complete my task through some other webGL / canvas operation?

Rendering on a server or proxying is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Comment: @NullPointer I am not asking to use getImageData ( not possible ), but to make the same transformation using a canvas / webgl api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL does not work with cross-origin textures at all. There's [an extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_security_sensitive_resources/) in the draft, but it's not yet standardized, and it only allows then in limited scenarios, so samplers using such textures still can't be used in conditional expressions.

With classic canvas, you can achieve a large number of color effects with clever use of blending modes. There is a list of them [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), or a more technical description on [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/).

In particular, a very useful trick involves the use of `color-dodge` operation. By using very bright constant color as your source, it effectively multiplies the background image by a large value, which lets us do thresholding operations.

In your case, you can use the following code to "select" all pixels with a certain color:

```
// 1. Use 'difference' to make all matching pixels black
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.fillStyle = srcColor;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
// 2. Use 'color-dodge' trick to turn all non-black pixels into white
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";
ctx.fillStyle = "#fefefe";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

// Steps 3 and 4 are only necessary if full RGB matching is required
// Without these steps, matching will be done on per-channel basis 
// 3*. Desaturate the image, ensuring all three channels have the same value
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
// 4*. Use color-dodge again, to mask pixels where all 3 components matched
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";
ctx.fillStyle = "#fefefe";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

// 5. Invert the image to make matching pixels white and the rest black
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
// 6. Multiply by desired color
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
ctx.fillStyle = dstColor;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

Here's an live example implementing your code (the left half of the output image looks black, because you can't see dark colors like `rgb(1,0,0)`):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function makeImage(w, h) {
  const c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  return c;
}

function paintSource(c) {
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  for (let x = 0; x < c.width; ++x) {
    for (let y = 0; y < c.height; ++y) {
      const i = (y * c.width + x) * 4;
      const v = Math.round((x + y) / 2);
      // 1, 2 or 3
      data.data[i] = Math.floor(x * 3 / c.width) + 1;
      data.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
}

function selectColor(srcCanvas, dstCanvas, srcColor, dstColor) {
  const ctx = dstCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(srcCanvas, 0, 0);
  const w = srcCanvas.width, h = srcCanvas.height;
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
  ctx.fillStyle = srcColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fefefe";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  ctx.fillStyle = dstColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

const source = makeImage(256, 256);
paintSource(source);

const c1 = makeImage(256, 256);
selectColor(source, c1, "rgb(1,0,0)", "rgb(50,0,0)");
const c2 = makeImage(256, 256);
selectColor(source, c2, "rgb(2,0,0)", "rgb(100,0,0)");
const c3 = makeImage(256, 256);
selectColor(source, c3, "rgb(3,0,0)", "rgb(255,0,0)");

ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
ctx.drawImage(c1, 256, 0);
ctx.drawImage(c2, 256, 0);
ctx.drawImage(c3, 256, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
```

Here's a slightly more complicated example that demonstrates thresholding: https://jsfiddle.net/Rivvy/kq2ga90z/35/

Comment: Wow! Can't wait to try it out! @riv

Comment: Am unsure where the original image(which I want to transform) fits in here.

Comment: That would be the "source" image - instead of generating it with paintSource you load it from url.

Comment: thanks! one last question - What to do when part of the source image has a completely black area?

Comment: You can do the same with srcColor set to black, it will select all black areas on the image.

Comment: Yes, but I am worried about step 1, difference,  in which I am making all matching pixels black. won't they mix with the pixels originally black?