# HTML Canvas getting pixel data from one image to use in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a written a code which randomly generates a specified number of non-overlapping circles onto a canvas element.  I want my code to take an image and map the colors from the image onto the circles on the canvas.  For ease of use I created two canvases side by side each 300px by 300px.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height= 300;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


var can=document.getElementById("hide");
can.width = 300;
can.height = 300;
var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("taco");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

I have a circles class which requires all circles to have an x, y, radius, and color.

```
class Circles {
    constructor(x,y,radius){
        this.x =x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color= color;
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI *2, false);
        c.strokeStyle = 'black';
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle =this.color;
        c.fill();
    }
}
```

Lastly I run a for loop to generate a specified number of circles and check if any circles overlap.  I am using `getImageData` to attempt to find the pixel color of the image on one of the canvases and use that color to fill a circle on the other canvas.

```
function setup() {
    for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
        let x = Math.random()*300;
        let y = Math.random()*300;
        let pixel= ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1)
        let data = pixel.data;
        let color = `rgba(${data[0]},${data[1]},${data[2]},${(data[3]/255)})`
        let circle = new Circles(x,y,2,color);

        let overlapping = false
        for(let j=0; j< circleArray.length; j++){
            let other = circleArray[j];
            let d = dist(circle.x,other.x,circle.y,other.y);
            if(d < circle.radius + other.radius){
                overlapping = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(overlapping== false){
            circleArray.push(circle);
            //console.log(circleArray);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that seems common in Canvas:

```
client.js:49 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

I tried the solutions on this page but the image I am using is a downloaded png and none of those solutions seem to work.

[How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Comment: Can you create a fully functional code snippet with your issue?

Comment: Your code is not functional. You have no `circleArray` defined. You are using an undeclared function dist() and you need to add a color argument to the circle constructor. Please create a fully functional code example.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the full code.  In my browser this code creates black circles however that doesn't happen in the jsfiddle and I'm not sure why. https://jsfiddle.net/tdammon/854wxkvs/12/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work because your img is broken, but anyway, your fiddle would be useless here since what we really need to know is how you do serve this image. If the `<img id="taco" width="300" height="300" src="Frog-1.png">` is really as is in your code, then one of the only thing I could see is `file://` protocol security: Are you on a server (even localhost) or are you serving your page directly from your HDD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

Comment: @Kaiido I am serving directly from my hard drive.  My issue is different from others I have found on stack overflow because my image is not being sourced from the web.  I'm not sure if that actually makes our issues different but it seems relevant given the error I get.

Comment: @user8735495 Please read the duplicate, and my comment. **file:// protocol is considered as single origin by some browsers**: your image will taint the canvas. To circumvent this, run a server. And this is exactly the same case as in the proposed dupe.