# I am trying to draw the animation on the canvas but i get this error "The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Tags: javascript, canvas

Full error from chrome DevTools

```
nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1200
 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at Object.drawImageToBackground (file:///C:/Users/hovorun/Desktop/site%20original/phore.io/wp-content/themes/salient/js/nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1200:50)
    at Object.callDrawImageToBackground (file:///C:/Users/hovorun/Desktop/site%20original/phore.io/wp-content/themes/salient/js/nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1130:27)
    at Image.bgImage.(anonymous function).onload (file:///C:/Users/hovorun/Desktop/site%20original/phore.io/wp-content/themes/salient/js/nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:782:23)
<br>
```

Here is my code, i just can't drop it here cause there are so many letters more than are allowed
Please explain me what i am doing wrong

https://pastebin.com/W5Ykt5AV

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)