# OpenSeadragon local html error: crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous' make the demo image unvisible in local html

Tags: anonymous, openseadragon

(The whole package can be downloaded from
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vzAYq909e4H7qwZ-opAehmWIHkcjVM1c/view?usp=sharing)

I would like to try the OpenSeaDragon demo:

Source code:
https://github.com/usnistgov/OpenSeadragonFiltering
The same online demo:
https://pages.nist.gov/OpenSeadragonFiltering/

to make html and associated js files etc to demo in my local computer.

To try the demo on local computer, I download openseadragon and this demo, and highsmith tile image folders, and all the js files needed from the demo website. Then I replace the code in index.html by the dynamic code in the browser for the demo website.
Then I change all the http path in js and html to local file, and specify the viewer object in demo,js and demo-bundle.js as below:

```
var viewer = new OpenSeadragon({
    id: 'openseadragon',
    prefixUrl: './images/',
    //crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous' 
    tileSources: {
        Image: {
            xmlns: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008',
            Url: './highsmith_files/',
            Overlap: '2',
            TileSize: '256',
            Format: 'jpg',
            Size: {
                Height: '9221',
                Width: '7026'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If I remove/comment the line:

```
crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous'
```

then I open index.html and could see exactly the loaded image and filter options. But once I click an filter, although the filter was added to the lower part, but the image turns black forever. The console explorer said:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at Object.tileDrawingHandler [as handler] (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:45407:57)
    at file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:28662:34
    at $.Viewer.raiseEvent (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:28684:14)
    at _drawingHandler (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:43338:23)
    at $.Tile.drawCanvas (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:40996:10)
    at $.Drawer.drawTile (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:41659:23)
    at drawTiles (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:44495:29)
    at updateViewport (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:43944:6)
    at $.TiledImage.draw (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:43390:10)
    at $.World.draw (file:///D:/QMDownload/9/test3/OpenseadragonDemo/_plugins/demo-bundle.js:45070:29)
```

I googled and find an answer that
[How to fix getImageData() error The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

```
As others have said you are "tainting" the canvas by loading from a cross origins domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

    However, you may be able to prevent this by simply setting:
    
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    This only works if the remote server sets the following header appropriately:
    
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    The Dropbox file chooser when using the "direct link" option is a great example of this. I use it on oddprints.com to hoover up images from the remote dropbox image url, into my canvas, and then submit the image data back into my server. All in javascript
```

So I bring back the

```
crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous'
```

in demo,js and demo-bundle.js, but found that when I open index.html, the image was total black.

How can I solve the problem and make the filter work in local computer ?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you running locally? Are you just loading files directly from your hard drive or are you running a local server? I think you may need a local server for this.

Comment: Hi, I just use  browser to open the html files without internet  involved. If I open with IE explorer, and allow the blocked content, then the image was shown and filter works well. However, if I open with Chrome browser or other non-IE browser, the image was  shown when html was opened, but when I apply any filter, the image was gone and totally black in the canvas. It seems that getImageData command is not allowed locally, so I need to use TCP/IP port to mimic surfing internet to get access to these html file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure for this scenario you need to have a local server running. I don't know what the easiest way to do that on Windows would be. I believe XAMPP is one good option: https://www.apachefriends.org/ Or you could write a little Node server: https://nodejs.org/ Here's another suggestion (using Python): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server  Or maybe just IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms181052(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN