# Using canvas image on local machine

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-origin-read-blocking, getimagedata

I would like to load an image into a `<canvas>` on my laptop so I can use `getImageData()`. I am using javascript in a local .html file. It is not a live, web facing project. Just a personal project.

I get the error: **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
at Image.loadedImage** when I try and do this.

What is the easiest solution to this problem? I *think* in the past I may have installed an Apache server just to address this issue! I just tried [hfs](https://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) but it did not work (to fix this issue).

Note that this cannot be fixed using `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"` or by running on Firefox as other, out of date, answers to related problems have suggested.

Comment: adding `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"` to your image might help [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Comment: Without CORS, you cannot access the contents of images. This also applies when copying the image to a canvas (the canvas becomes tainted). `file:` urls always fail the CORS checks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I've found that installing and running [Rebex](https://www.rebex.net/tiny-web-server/) solves the problem (must transfer files to `wwwroot`)

Comment: This is because Rebex is a web server and so you're no longer accessing the files via `file:` urls. Any web server would have worked.

Comment: Probably the best way to do this would be to run the Rebex executable in the folder the original .html file was in. Then you just move everything into the wwwroot folder, in that folder.

Comment: @Ouroborus, yes, thanks, I think I get it. Pity that is the only way to do it. Rebex seems like a good solution as it is basically no setup required and very easy to manage.

Comment: @Ouroborus, curious that hfs didn't work then. Not sure why.

Comment: I suspect Rebex is HTTPS by default and HFS is HTTP by default. CORS generally needs HTTPS as a secure context. HTTP can work, but supports far less capability. For example, you may notice that a lot of the newer web APIs require HTTPS/CORS along with the correct permissions.

Comment: @Ouroborus. I just checked how I am accessing and I'm using http://localhost... so its not that. No matter, I have a working solution. Thanks.