# Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, remotion

I am using Remotion Video Player.

I am using video player in multiple components, over there when I am passing remote video link its getting rendered, but in this component for the same Video Player when I am passing remote URL its giving me Error : SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Here is the Screenshot1 attached of the error :
[image: ScreenShot1]

Below is the code :

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AbsoluteFill, useVideoConfig, Video, staticFile } from "remotion";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
let videoUrl='https://examplevideo.com/VHS+Heavy+White.mov'
const videoAsset = videoUrl


export const Greenscreen: React.FC<{
  opacity: number;
}> = ({ opacity }) => {
  const video = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const canvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const { width, height } = useVideoConfig();

  // Process a frame
  const onVideoFrame = useCallback(
    (opacity: number) => {
      if (!canvas.current || !video.current) {
        return;
      }
      const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");

      if (!context) {
        return;
      }

      context.drawImage(video.current, 0, 0, width, height);
      const imageFrame = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
      const { length } = imageFrame.data;

      // If the pixel is very green, reduce the alpha channel
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        const red = imageFrame.data[i + 0];
        const green = imageFrame.data[i + 1];
        const blue = imageFrame.data[i + 2];
        if (green > 200 && red < 200 && blue < 200) {
          imageFrame.data[i + 3] = opacity * 255;
        }
      }
      context.putImageData(imageFrame, 0, 0);
    },
    [height, width]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = video;
    if (!current || !current.requestVideoFrameCallback) {
      return;
    }
    let handle = 0;
    const callback = () => {
      onVideoFrame(opacity);
      handle = current.requestVideoFrameCallback(callback);
    };

    callback();

    return () => {
      current.cancelVideoFrameCallback(handle);
    };
  }, [onVideoFrame, opacity]);

  return (
    <AbsoluteFill>
      <AbsoluteFill>
        <Video
          ref={video}
          style={{ opacity: 0 }}
          startFrom={0}
          src={videoAsset}
        />
      </AbsoluteFill>
      <AbsoluteFill>
        <canvas ref={canvas} width={width} height={height} />
      </AbsoluteFill>
    </AbsoluteFill>
  );
};
```

Expecting the video player to accept remote url and render video. Its rendering video in another component were i am using the same video player with remote video link.

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097747/how-to-fix-getimagedata-error-the-canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data) help ?

Comment: Nopes that did't worked!