# DOM Security Exception 18: Tainted Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I'm nearly finished with a Javascript/HTML5-based game, and i've been testing it by using Chrome to open the HTML page on my local file system (i haven't uploaded anything anywhere). I'm using Chrome's `file://` protocol to do this. But i'm running into a problem... At the beginning of the game, i display an image for a couple seconds before moving onto the menu screen. I pause the game by grabbing the canvas' pixel data, displaying that, then drawing a semi-transparent rectangle across the whole thing, with a crosshair as a custom pointer. However, Chrome is giving me trouble about a DOM Security Exception 18: `"Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."`

So i did some research on the Internet, and it turns out this is because Chrome sees that the image is grabbed from the local file system, and sees this as a security error. Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas) as a reference, i tried doing some research on Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, but quickly got lost. I figured it would be much easier to simply open the test HTML file using `http://` and `localhost` like the question answerer suggested. But i have no idea how to do this, either.

I'd really like to use Chrome to continue testing my game (the developer tools accessed through `Ctrl-Shift-I` have proved to be invaluable), so i figured there were three solutions: Either figure out what CORS is and how to use it, learn how to open a local file using `http://`, or somehow hard-code my image data as a variable in my JavaScript script file (like a XPM file in C). I don't know how to do the first two, and i'm trying to avoid the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s probably time to download a local web server or sign up for a hosted server.

But if you want to continue testing without a server, you can sign up for a free dropbox.com account and host your images there.

Dropbox allows access to images using CORS friendly crossOrigin=”anonymous”.

Then CORS is no problem on Chrome & Mozilla.  But, IE still fails to be CORS friendly—come on IE :(

Here’s how to load an image without CORS problems from dropbox (Chrome & Mozilla, not IE).

The “secret” is setting  image.crossOrigin=”anonymous” before setting the image.src:

```
    var externalImage2=document.createElement("img");
    externalImage2.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=externalImage2.width;
        canvas.height=externalImage2.height;
        ctx.drawImage(externalImage2,0,0);
        // use getImageData to replace blue with yellow
        var imageData=recolorImage(externalImage2,0,0,255,255,255,0);
        // put the altered data back on the canvas  
        // this will FAIL on a CORS violation
        ctxAnonymous.putImageData(imageData,0,0);    
    }
    externalImage2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    externalImage2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/colorhouse.png";
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YdzHT/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasCORS=document.getElementById("canvasCORS");
    var ctxCORS=canvasCORS.getContext("2d");
    var canvasAnonymous=document.getElementById("canvasAnonymous");
    var ctxAnonymous=canvasAnonymous.getContext("2d");

    // Using image WITHOUT crossOrigin=anonymous
    // Fails in all browsers
    var externalImage1=new Image();
    externalImage1.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=externalImage1.width;
        canvas.height=externalImage1.height;
        ctx.drawImage(externalImage1,0,0);
        // use getImageData to replace blue with yellow
        var imageData=recolorImage(externalImage1,0,0,255,255,255,0);
        // put the altered data back on the canvas  
        // this will FAIL on a CORS violation
        ctxCORS.putImageData(imageData,0,0);    
    }
    externalImage1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/colorhouse.png";

    // Using image WITH crossOrigin=anonymous
    // Succeeds in Chrome+Mozilla, Still fails in IE
    var externalImage2=new Image();
    externalImage2.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=externalImage2.width;
        canvas.height=externalImage2.height;
        ctx.drawImage(externalImage2,0,0);
        // use getImageData to replace blue with yellow
        var imageData=recolorImage(externalImage2,0,0,255,255,255,0);
        // put the altered data back on the canvas  
        // this will FAIL on a CORS violation
        ctxAnonymous.putImageData(imageData,0,0);    
    }
    externalImage2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    externalImage2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/colorhouse.png";


    function recolorImage(img,oldRed,oldGreen,oldBlue,newRed,newGreen,newBlue){
        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;
        c.width = w;
        c.height = h;

        // draw the image on the temporary canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

        // pull the entire image into an array of pixel data
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);

        // examine every pixel, 
        // change any old rgb to the new-rgb
        for (var i=0;i<imageData.data.length;i+=4)
          {
              // is this pixel the old rgb?
              if(imageData.data[i]==oldRed &&
                 imageData.data[i+1]==oldGreen &&
                 imageData.data[i+2]==oldBlue
              ){
                  // change to your new rgb
                  imageData.data[i]=newRed;
                  imageData.data[i+1]=newGreen;
                  imageData.data[i+2]=newBlue;
              }
          }
        return(imageData);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Original external image</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=140 height=140></canvas>
    <p>.getImageData with .crossOrigin='anonymous'
    <p>[Succeeds in Chrome+Mozilla, still fails in IE]</p>
    <canvas id="canvasAnonymous" width=140 height=140></canvas>
    <p>.getImageData without .crossOrigin='anonymous'
    <p>[Fails on all browsers]</p>
    <canvas id="canvasCORS" width=140 height=140></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Developing using the local file system is generally not a good idea for precisely the reason you have discovered. To use the `localhost` option you'll need a web server installed on your PC. Google for a WAMP package (Windows, Apache. MysQL, PHP) which should give you everything you need.

Unfortunately, CORS will only work for you if you have a web server!

[edit] You can get a WAMP server from [wampserver.com](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), obviously!

Comment: So, i'll have to upload to a remote server every time i change something?

Comment: Not if you install a WAMP server - the web server runs locally. FWIW I run a separate web server for development, and I do have to upload every time I want to test a change.

Comment: @creXALBO If you just need a light-weight server for local development, then Mongoose is probably a better alterntive: https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Comment: @K3N but mongoose is not working. I ran mongoose from the folder where my files are located but it still gives me the error: "canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data".