# fabric.Image.fromURL show errror when load large images in FIREFOX

Tags: fabricjs

I am using Fibricjs on my application. I got an error when i was using fabric.Image.fromURL function with Firefox.

I recorded a video about this bug.

http://www.screenr.com/6hSN

And here is demo:

```
    [1] http://jsfiddle.net/buidan/9JJfC/1/ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        var logo;
        fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.petguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/american-eskimo-dog-1.jpg', function(img) {
            logo = img.set({ left: 20, top: 20, angle: -10 })
            canvas.add(logo);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    });
```

P/S:
On chrome it worked fine. The problem just showing on Firefox
I am using firefox 28.0 (latest version)

Please give me an advise for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is a Cross Origin Request issue. I tested your jsfiddle with the Firefox Addon [Force CORS](https://github.com/jo5ef/Force-CORS) enabled and it worked fine. Check out the answers of this post: [Cross-origin data in HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972049/cross-origin-data-in-html5-canvas).
Hope this helps.